# implementing lighting in shader file all my objects turn black

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

My colors are definitely showing up because when I add 0.8 to the final result color you can see them just barely.  I have not done any code for lighting in main other than a uniform vector 3 called Light_Position and enabling lighting, is there code required in main to grab surface normals and other stuff?  If so let me know what I need to do.

in main for lighting:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);


glm::vec3 Light_Position(0.2f, 0.1f, 0.2f);
int lightpos = glGetUniformLocation(shader, “light_position”);
glUniformMatrix4fv(lightpos, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Light_Position));
```

---

```
//Both fragment and vertex shaders in one file

#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;

uniform mat4 perspective;

uniform mat4 just_translations;

uniform vec3 light_position;

out vec3 fragment_position;
out vec3 Normals;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = model_matrix * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
    fragment_position = vec3(just_translations * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0));
    Normals = mat3(transpose(inverse(just_translations))) * normal;
}
```

Comment: Is `model_matrix` the same as `perspective * just_translations`? If yes, then the name is misleading. It should by  `mvp_matrix` (model view projection matrix).

Comment: Where is the fragment shader?